# What is the best way to theme page--front with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to create a user dashboard by design a flat menu for page--front.tpl.php, and the twitter 3.0 bootstrap. My current site is using Omega's OHM responsive theme as default, so my question is, how do I apply twitter bootstrap to just a SINGLE tpl file?

There's a part 2 if its related, copying page.tpl.php and calling it page--front.tpl.php isn't being recognized (I do this within ohms templates/system dir, and cleared cache). I've read through Drupal.se, and googled it and tried the variety of things - but I guess I don't understand how drupal recognizes page--front. Do I assign a piece of content as home page then it gets applied? If so, that's the page I need specifically themed with bootstrap only.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to switch the theme entirely. You could simply use something like: https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey

Regarding the regcognition of page--front.tpl.php, 
rename your existing page.tlp.php to page--default.tpl.php

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be hard to do because there is still div wrappers in the html.tpl.php that going to show depending on your theme settings.

But if you clone your page.tpl.php to be page--front.tpl.php and then flush your cache, that template should be active. It will always theme the home page, regardless of what type of page it is set as (i.e. the default node listing, a node or view).

However, I would recommend using something like themekey as Jbartsch suggested, or just switch the entire site theme to a bootstrap based one, which is what I just did.